# Export Pages with javascript in Adobe Acrobat X Pro

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

Thanks for the help.   I am trying to use Adobe Acrobat X Pro to extract pages from PDFs.  I have a folder which contains about 300 PDFs.  I only need to last three pages of each file.

I have used the following line (found [in this tutorial](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/extracting-pages-pdf-acrobat-javascript)) within Adobe Acrobat as a guided action.

```
this.extractPages(this.numPages-3,this.numPages-1,)
```

A guided action allows a user to perform the action on all files in a folder.  This line produces the last three pages but does not save the file.  It opens a temporary PDF file and goes to the next file in the folder.  After a dozen or so files my computer freezes because of all the temporary files created.     I need a way to save and close each file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a path to save the new document, this is what the `cPath` parameter to `Doc.extractPages()` does:

```
this.extractPages({
    nStart: this.numPages-3, 
    cPath: '/C/some/dir/' + this.documentFileName
});
this.closeDoc(false); // to close the current document
```

See: [Acrobat JS API Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm)